# построение графика для решение интеграла методом Симпсона

Tags: python, matplotlib

Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста, сделать график с помощью библиотеки matplotlib. + подскажите как сюда можно проверку методом Рунге сделать 
Вот изначальный код

```
import numpy as np

def simps(f,a,b,N=50):

    if N % 2 == 1:
        raise ValueError("N must be an even integer.")
    dx = (b - a) / N
    x = np.linspace(a, b, N + 1)
    y = f(x)
    S = dx / 3 * np.sum(y[0:-1:2] + 4 * y[1::2] + y[2::2])
    return S

print(simps(lambda x : np.sqrt(16-x**2), -2,2,10))
```

Comment: Для начала прочитайте реализацию алгоритмов здесь: https://habr.com/ru/post/420867/ (глава "Кусочно-параболическая аппроксимация"). А уж построение графика - отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть это подойдет?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def simps(f,a,b,N=50):
    if N % 2 == 1:
        raise ValueError("N must be an even integer.")
    dx = (b - a) / N
    x = np.linspace(a, b, N + 1)
    y = f(x)
    S = dx / 3 * np.sum(y[0:-1:2] + 4 * y[1::2] + y[2::2])
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.axvline(a)
    plt.axvline(b)
    plt.axhline(0)
    return S

print(simps(lambda x : np.sqrt(16-x**2), -2,2,10))
```